# FullCalendar - get an external link to highlight existing event

Tags: fullcalendar

I would like to use an external text link - to highlight an existing FullCalendar event on my calendar.

- link 1 (clicking link 1 will highlight the background color of existing
  event 1)
- link 2 (clicking link 2 will highlight the background color of existing
  event 2)
- link 3 (clicking link 3 will highlight the background color of existing
  event 3)

---

I can't think of any way to do this other than having a unique ID.

Is there a way to simply assign your own unique ID to lets say the `<tr>` or `<td>` tag,  i.e.

`<td id='my_id_1'>`

when the events are rendering - so that I can utilize this ID to know which event to highlight?

Answer (score 2):

I came up with something that works.

When loading my calendar events:

```
eventRender: function(event, element){

     element.attr("id","my_id_1");

},
```

Now I can just call:

```
$('#my_id_1').addClass('my_red_highlight_class');
```

To highlight the background when clicking my text link.